# Cassandra: 2.2.8: Properties specified [cold_reads_to_omit] are not understood by SizeTieredCompactionStrategy

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

- using cassandra 2.2.8

Is there a work around available for the `cold_reads_to_omit` attribute?

```
cassandra@cqlsh:> ALTER TABLE data.ale_state WITH compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'cold_reads_to_omit': 0.0};
ConfigurationException: Properties specified [cold_reads_to_omit] are not understood by SizeTieredCompactionStrategy
cassandra@cqlsh:>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported in 2.2, don't use this property.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9203

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9997